# how do I "roll" for a 25% chance to get YES or NO?

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to randomly generate a YES or NO based on a percentage

So I want to "roll" and have a 25% chance to hit YES, a 75% chance to hit NO

Was hoping someone could point me in the right direction on the best way to do this, maybe some article or something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All of the other answers seem to focus on the percentage of YES being 25%, which is a probability of 1/4.  But what if the percentage is an arbitrary integer between 0 and 100?

```
BOOL randomBoolWithYesPercentage(int percentage) {
    return arc4random_uniform(100) < percentage;
}
```

Call it with the percentage, like `randomBoolWithYesPercentage(25)`.

And what if the percentage can be fractional, like 37.6%?  Then we need to get more sophisticated.  This should suffice:

```
BOOL randomBoolWithYesPercentage(double percentage) {
    double r = 100 * (double)arc4random() / ((double)UINT32_MAX + 1);
    return r < percentage;
}
```

Comment: Just a note: Percentage should be like "56.5" etc, not between 0.0 and 1.0.

Answer (score 5):

Use a random function with an equal distribution and make it as likely as you want to equal one of the possible values

```
BOOL RollWithDenominator(NSInteger denominator)
{
  return 0 == arc4random_uniform(denominator);
}
```

For a 1/4 chance call `RollWithDenominator(4);`

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo-code:

```
x = rand(1,4);
if (rand == 1) {
    'yes' // 25% of the time you get 1
} else {
    'no'; // the other 75%, when you get 2,3,4
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, probably should be a comment.
I have not much IOS experience but I am sure this can be easily applied / transferred.

An easy solution is to define some sort of array with four values.
Then randomly pick a value in this array.
Then with help of an if/else statement if it hits a specific single value output will be 'yes', if it hits any of the other three output will be 'no'.

---

EDIT:
Exactly what Marc B says.
You could also use an array such as `(1,0,0,0)` or `(yes,no,no,no)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way:

```
BOOL b = arc4random_uniform(4) == 0;
```

Comment: [arc4random_uniform() is recommended over constructions like arc4random() % upper_bound'' as it avoids "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/arc4random_uniform.3.html)

Comment: @Paul.s very good point. However, it just so happens 4 is a power of 2.

Comment: This is true but think of the next guy who comes along and copies your answer but does not use a power of two. Is it a massive problem? In most cases probably not but it's better to write exemplary code that can be replicated. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Since you are programming for iOS here is some code that you can use directly:

Call this at the start of your application, this will allow you to have different results every time you start your application:

```
srand (time(NULL));
```

Then at the point in your code where you need the random results you use:

```
BOOL result = false;
int randomValue = rand()%4;
if(randomValue==0)
{
    result = TRUE;
}
```

The variable 'result' is with 25% true and with 75% false!

Comment: Objective-C uses `YES/NO` for boolean values not `TRUE/false`

Comment: Never use rand() with modulo. It's biased.

Comment: Actually objective C understands both! YES/NO and TRUE/FALSE

Comment: And the low bits of rand() don't have enough entropy.